# GWT Fail to add nested LayoutPanel to FlowPanel

Tags: gwt, nested, flowpanel

I've been trying to add a view with LayoutPanel to another view  into a FlowPanel:

parent contains this:

```
<g:FlowPanel ui:field="innerContentPanel" />
```

child contains this:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">

<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui" xmlns:p1="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client"
xmlns:o="urn:import:com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations">
<g:HTMLPanel ui:field="parentView" >

    <g:LayoutPanel width="100%" height="15%" ui:field="innerPanel"
        styleName="inner_panel">...</g:LayoutPanel>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

i keep getting an error saying that the inherited panel's XML has no ui:field attribute for the innerContentPanel.

is there something i need to assure in the parent or child so that the child's xml doesn't look for e parent's variables?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post other pieces of code so that its easy to try out. Have you followed the span example - https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder .

Comment: This is very limited info. Post other pieces of code, and make sure that only one widget/panel is added to layout panel. Otherwise it is an error